# What does "apt-get install !!" do and how to make it work?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have seen someone typing

```
apt-get install !!
```

He did that a few times and every time, a different program was installed. It seems like it automatically figured out what is needed next.

However, when I tried it on my Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS virtual machine, it just showed some usage instructions. Googling for `apt-get install !!` doesn't seem to work very well. Many search results do not contain the double exclamation mark.

What does `apt-get install !!` do and what could be missing on my machine that it did not work?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15137461/3488231

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`!!` is a shortcut in bash that means last command executed.

Try this:

```
 echo hello
 !!
```

In this context, the `!!` will be expanded to another `echo hello`.

I imagine what happened was they tried to run a command and it failed and complained it wasn't installed.  So then they typed `sudo apt-get install !!` because the package name was coincidentally the same as the name of the command they tried to run.  The resulting command would attempt to install a package by the same name as the command they had just attempted to execute.

Comment: Yes, that's probably it. If I run `lynx`, see that it's not installed and then run `apt-get install !!` it installs lynx. It didn't work for me, because I tried `apt-get install !!` as the only command.

Comment: Another common use is when something should have been run as `sudo`, such as `apt-get install`ing something.

Comment: @A.L: you first type `apt-get install some-program`, and when you realise you don't have privileges, you just `sudo !!`, which expands to `sudo apt-get install some-program`.

Comment: `!!` is an alias for `!-1`, meaning the last item in bash history. `!-2` is the penultimate and so on.

Answer (score 41):

`!!` has nothing to do with `apt-get`. It is a shell keyword that will be expanded to the previous command. This expansion is done by shell before the current command is interpreted.

From `man bash`:

> !!     Refer to the previous command.  This is a synonym
>   for `!-1'.

For example, if you run a command:

```
echo "foo"
```

Then if you run:

```
sudo apt-get install !!
```

it will be expanded to :

```
sudo apt-get install echo foo
```

As you can see it is expanded into two packages namely `echo` and the other is `foo`. There is no standalone package named `foo` and `echo`. Apart from the shell builtin `echo` there is `/bin/echo` executable that is a part of the GNU-coreutils package. So, you will get errors saying that no such packages are available.

On the other hand the other person might be doing something like this:

```
$ cowsay
The program 'cowsay' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install cowsay

$ sudo apt-get install !!
sudo apt-get install cowsay
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  filters
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cowsay
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 119 not upgraded.
Need to get 18.5 kB of archives.
```

As you can see `cowsay` is being installed.

I would suggest you to not doing this (unless you are sure), being explicit does not harm.

Comment: Great explanation for the `!!`.  I knew what it meant, but I like the way you described it.

Comment: +1 for the warning not to try this at home.

Answer (score 16):

`!!` : Refer to the previous command. This is a synonym for `!-1` (The [source](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)).

For instance, if i execute:

```
./test
```

then remember that I need to be Root, then I could simply type:

```
sudo !!
```

it's the same as typing:

```
sudo ./test
```

It's useful when your last command contain a lot of characters.

Comment: Brilliant! I never thought about the `sudo !!` command; what I have been doing for years is press the up key once, then move the cursor all the way to the left and add `sudo`.

Comment: @IQAndreas Your way gives you the opportunity to double-check the command, which is not a bad thing when running `sudo`.

Comment: I always read "sudo !!" as "i meant sudo for f*** sake"

Comment: @Vixen: In that case, [thefuck](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck) could also be something for you

Comment: @IQAndreas moving the cursor all the way to the left seems too boring. Why not just `Ctrl+A` or at least `Home`?

Answer (score 2):

The question has already been answered, so I won't be repetitive. However, I would like to point out that there are numerous such shortcuts in various shells that help repeat/find/edit commands. Some of the ones that I use are:

1. `!$` followed by <kbd>ENTER</kbd> will type the last word of the last command. For example,

   ```
   ls -l /let/me/in
   cd !$
   ```

This will land you in `/let/me/in`

2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> and then type a few words from a previous command. For example, if you typed `vi /home/mycoolproject.sh` and followed it up with some random commands like `ls`, `cd`, `pwd`, etc. then just typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> followed by `cool` will pull up that `vi` command.

Just search for bash (or csh or whatever) keyboard shortcuts and it will be the best thing you did today!