# What !! means while calling echo

Tags: command-line, echo

Could somebody explain this output?

```
$ echo !
!
$ echo !!
echo echo !
echo !
$
```

I expected sedond echo to write only `!!`

Comment: If you view your command `history` & decide you want to run command 419 in that history, you can type `!419` and it'll execute.  Provided answers tell you  `!!` executes your last command, but it has other uses too :)

Comment: Same question, although different context: https://askubuntu.com/q/627781/295286 Effectively duplicate

Comment: To prevent the `!!` from being evaluated (it's being evaluated prior to executing the echo cmd), use quotes, eg `echo '!!'` https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!!` means the last executed command.

`echo !!` will echo the last command, which was `echo !` in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Easily explained:

```
$ echo 1
1
$ !!
echo 1
1
```

so `!!` just repeats the last command, so

```
echo !!
```

*does **excactly** what it's supposed to to!*

### ;-)